# Script consuming extreme amounts of CPU

Tags: python, pyautogui, pynput

I have a programme, which moves the mouse by certain coordinates when held down and it stops it when the mouse key is released. However the code below is taking up 90%+ of my CPU at time. How would I make the code below more efficient / take up less of my CPU's resources?

```
import pynput
import pyautogui

delta_x = [1,2,3]
delta_y = [3,2,1]
def on_press_start(*args):
    if args[-1]:
        return False

def on_press_loop(*args):
    if not args[-1]:
        return False



while True:
    i = 0
    with Listener(on_click=on_press_start) as listener:
        listener.join()

    with Listener(on_click=on_press_loop) as listener:
        for i in range(len(delta_x)):
            pyautogui.move(delta_x[i],delta_y[i])
            if not listener.running:
                break
            print(i)
```

Comment: have you tried adding sleep() in your while loop?

Comment: @Tranbi, thanks for the comment however I would like there to be as little of a delay between each iteration of the while loop / mouse click and release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even a simple

```
while True:
    pass
```

loop will use 100% of a CPU core. The efficiency of the code inside the loop will only effect the frequency. It won't effect the CPU usage unless you limit the frequency.

In your case, you don't need a `while` loop to monitor the mouse. The listener provided by the library does that for you but in a smarter way. From the [docs](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse):

```
# create a listener
listener = mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click)

...

# start listening to clicks
listener.start()

...

# stop listening to clicks
listener.stop()
```

When to start/stop listening to mouse events depends on your use case.

Example where the on_click and on_move events are used:

```
from pynput import mouse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    state = {
        "left_button_pressed": False
    }

    def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
        if button == mouse.Button.left:
            state["left_button_pressed"] = pressed
            print("onclick", x, y, button, pressed)

    def on_move(*args):
        if state["left_button_pressed"]:
            print("on_move", *args)

    with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click, on_move=on_move) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be the most probable cause. When removing the while loop, the whole function only runs once (one click & one release long), could incorporate your changes to the code (provided in the question) in your answer?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html,

> A mouse listener is a threading.Thread, and all callbacks will be invoked from the thread.

which means that the more Listener you create the more CPU threads it creates, You've a while true loop which will create a ton of listener and a ton of threads due to which your progamme is taking too much CPU.

Comment: How would I stop the Listeners then, using Listener.stop or listener.stop() at the end of the while loop? Both seem to work, which one should I use?

Comment: @jr123456jr987654321 It shall be fine if you don't use while True loop, I didn't really get the point of loop there. Listeners itself is a daemon and never ending process (unless killed or exited) so it won't necessarily need a while loop.

Comment: The while loop is there to allow the macro to be performed several times as long as the mouse is clicked and released, I ran some tests using Listener.stop did not really work. So how would I kill the Listener?

Comment: It's not about killing the listener, it's about spawning it once instead of infinite times. I would suggest reaing a bit more about how the listener works and how it's intended to be used

Comment: You don't have to create multiple listeners! Single listener is able to listen for the same event again again and again.

Comment: Ok, how would I then make the programme work (with the while loop) and only create a single listener?

Comment: Yep, a single listeners should do the work.

Comment: Could you change the code in the question to incorporate your approach as my attempts resulted in functionality being lost?